# Why QGraphicsPixmapItem do not have setParent()

Tags: pointers, qt5

QGraphicsPixmapItem does not like other qt object which inherited from QObject. It can not be destroyed when its parent destroy. Is the only way to use it is delete the pointer by myself?

```c
......

QGraphicsPixmapItem * backGround = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap::fromImage(this->mat2QImage(img)), NULL);

this->scene->addItem(backGround);
ui.imgDisplay->setScene(scene);
ui.imgDisplay->show();

......

// delete by myself
delete backGround;

// why can not I set the parent of the QGraphicsPixmapItem to QGraphicsScene
// when QGraphicsScene destroy, QGraphicsPixmapItem under QGraphicsScene automatically destroy.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QGraphicsPixmapItem` inherits from `QGraphicsItem`, not `QObject`.

A `QgraphicsItem` is deleted when the scene is deleted. It will also delete all its children. So, you don't have delete yourself the items.

If you want a graphics item based on `QObject`, you should take a look to `QGraphicsObject`.